# An error was encountered performing the requested operation:ORA-00604:

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying connection to the Oracle database but this error display :

`An error was encountered performing the requested operation:ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated00604. 00000 - "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"*Cause: An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement(a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).*Action: If the situation described in the next error on the stackcan be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.`

what is the wrong and how can I solve it ?

Comment: How are you trying to do that? Error says that "quoted string wasn't properly terminated". I don't see any "quoted string"; did you use any? Which one?

Comment: The important part is `error occurred at recursive SQL level` - i.e. it is not *your* query that fails.  Was the installation OK?

Comment: _"I am trying connection to the Oracle database "_  suggests that you are getting the error _at the time you try to connect_.  But the nature of the error suggests you get the error _after_ you've connected and are trying to execute something.  Please update your opening question to clarify.  And remember, no one can debug code they cannot see.

Comment: Maybe there's some database trigger that fails after you get connected. You should investigate the issue with your DBA